# redirect after payment with perfect money in laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect

I have a payment gateway perfect money added into a site and after the payment completes it redirects to the defined route but with the error message and we have to refresh the page to work.
Is there anything I can add here?

```
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENT_URL" value="{{route('purchased.success')}}">
```

Comment: use jquery/javascript to reload the page to which your PG sends reponse.

Comment: can you explain how?

Comment: you can use the script - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48558109/3238940 in your error response page. But a better approch would be to redirect post response to get response

Comment: I have to add a URL in the input field it goes to that URL automatically when the payment is successful.
the redirect is ok but have to refresh the page

Comment: can you post me your routes? By the way you want to refresh the page that payment gateway redirects you after success/failed transaction rgt?

Comment: yes exactly that.both the routes have same issue.
 Route::get('purchased_success', ['as' => 'purchased.success', 'uses' => 'UserController@purchasedSuccess']);

Comment: add the script to the blade file used in 'purchasedSuccess' and the page will reload as you were expecting

Comment: but it will add # to the url I dont want that.
and I have to write it on both files

Comment: then you could use redirect to the same url. Add this 'return redirect(route('purchased.success'))' . This will rediect to the same route

Comment: i have to redirect it to homepage.if any user visits home page then its reloads twice?

Comment: add this meta tag to the head section of your blade file used in 'purchasedSuccess'  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url={{route('home')}}" />.

Comment: I add the meta tag but not working.
if I go to home page it keeps on refreshing

Comment: can you paste the controller code ?

Comment: public function purchasedSuccess()
    {
        session()->flash('success', 'Plan Purchased Successfully.');
        Session::flash('type', 'success');
        session()->flash('title','Success');
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

Comment: I am afraid that it's not possible to reload or out of reach from knowledge !. In this case you need to a route,  public function purchasedSuccess()
    {
        session()->flash('success', 'Plan Purchased Successfully.');
        Session::flash('type', 'success');
        session()->flash('title', 'Success');
        //reloading page with in controller
        return view('paysuccess');
    }  and in the paysucess.blade.php add this <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url={{route('home')}}" />.  How to pass session to another route - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34493968/3238940

Comment: (or)     public function purchasedSuccess()
    {
        session()->flash('success', 'Plan Purchased Successfully.');
        Session::flash('type', 'success');
        session()->flash('title', 'Success');
        //reloading page with in controller
        return route('paysuccessredirect');
    }
//New route
    public function paysuccessredirect(){
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

Comment: its not going into the controller function.It just open the route with error and When I refresh then the controller functions runs thats the issue.

Comment: do you use any debugger for laravel ? or what does your chrome network tab show

Comment: Status Code: 419 unknown status

Comment: what payment gateway are you using ? Does the PG share response to you in Get or POST request ?

Comment: Perfect Money. 
<form action="https://perfectmoney.is/api/step1.asp" method="POST" id="payment_form">

Comment: update your route to Route::post('purchased_success', ['as' => 'purchased.success', 'uses' => 'UserController@purchasedSuccess']); and controller to  public function purchasedSuccess() {
      session()->flash('success', 'Plan Purchased Successfully.'); 
      Session::flash('type', 'success');
       session()->flash('title','Success');
        return redirect()->route('home'); 
        } .. Remove all the scripts and meta tags added earlier

Comment: its still the same.could it be the session issue or something?

Comment: may be, try disabling csrf in verifycsrftoken.php for the particular route